# AEM6 CQ how to handle Component Development and Content Authoring happening at the same time?

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I just started at my new job and found myself right in the middle of a big project using Adobe AEM CQ, which I've never used before. Currently there are developers creating and tweaking components while content authors are busy authoring about 65 pages of content using those components.

Obviously, every time a component changes someone needs to update all the authored content with the new component changes. This is a huge time-waster as it seems like the only way to do this is through a custom made script that looks for nodes in the xml files and tries to convert them to the new component specs. Sometimes this is not even possible and authors need to re-author tons of stuff and lose lots of time.

Can anyone with AEM experience please let me know if:
1) There is a more painless way to migrate authored content to new components?
2) There is a better way to have developers and authors work simultaneously?

I know that the ideal way is to develop components first, and then author on top of those but it seems unrealistic especially with a big client project where things change all the time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it sounds like a business process problem.  The components should be fully developed and fully tested before content is being added by the authors.  If the edits to components are so different that you're having this problem, i would recommend having functional and technical requirements written before the build starts.
With that said, the Groovy console for AEM is an excellent tool for updating nodes and content within an AEM site.  Take a look at it here: https://github.com/Citytechinc/cq-groovy-console

Answer (score 0):

I would not agree that content production should happen after all the components where developed. It's beneficial, especially when the content production will take a lot of time, to start it while the development is happening.
On the other hand I completely agree with the other part of the answer. Groovy Console is a way to go, when dealing with content migration (both before Go Live and after, during BAU process). Ideal situation is where all the current content can be mapped to data in new version of component. Then you should be able to migrate all the content with scripts. If that's not the case then you can't run away from authors putting the content manually.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely components should be fully developed before their usage.
But if you want to change something specific in a component which will remain same for the entire website just like logo component or header component you can look into the **Design Dialog**.

So advantage of it is:

If you have already done authoring for n pages, when you change the component using Design Dialog it will be automatically reflected in all the pages wherever the component is being used.

Answer (score 0):

AEM is a CMS where content is your data is put it in simpler terms. If your development process is such that data is inconsistent with the UI after every release then your delivery process might be at fault. You can use the following ways to make things better:

- Make components backward compatible with the data
- Make components version-able, i.e. new versions of components work with new models of data and it's left to the user to use new versions.
- Provision for data or component migration in your project plan.

In practice, most AEM implementation make components backward compatible and provide an upgrade path to new versions. This is not a technical problem, it's more of a project governance issue.

> This post is resurfacing so don't want people to get wrong idea from the current state of answers (and some answers that should be comments IMHO) but the approach in general to deal with components and releases is not a technical problem of the platform.